# Why am i getting this warning: reason: Rules with neither input nor output files are always executed?

Tags: snakemake

So I have a snakemake code in a snakefile called fastqc.smk with a rule to run fastqc. I then have another main snakefile where I define rule all, supplying my expected output files. However, I am getting the warning **"reason: Rules with neither input nor output files are always executed."** More here:

```html
    jobid: 0
    reason: Rules with neither input nor output files are always executed.
    resources: tmpdir=<TBD>

Job stats:
job       count
------  -------
fastqc        1
total         1

Reasons:
    (check individual jobs above for details)
    neither input nor output:
        fastqc
```

Here is my fastqc rule:

```css
EXTENSIONS = ["zip", "html"]
rule fastqc:
    output:
        expand(
            FASTQC_DIR + "/{sample}_fastqc.{ext}",
            sample=[A, B], # as
            ext=EXTENSIONS,
        )
    input:
        *getInputFiles(DATA_DIR, "fastq.gz"),
    params:
        FASTQC_DIR 
    shell:
        """
        fastqc {input} -o {params}
        """
Here is where my rule all lies:
rule all:
    input:
        expand(
            FASTQC_DIR + "/{sample}_fastqc.{ext}",
            sample=[A, B],
            ext=EXTENSIONS,
        ),
```

Note: The *`getInputFiles(DATA_DIR, "fastq.gz")` is a function that allows me retrieve input files. It behaves well by retrieving the file paths.
`DATA_DIR` and `FASTQC_DIR` are defined elsewhere and works fine.